# delete.php page not deleting DB content

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system

I have been working on the admin side of my website now for a while.

I have successfully created an add page to add items to my mobi DB in mysql.

But when adding a delete.php page it does not work quite so well.

The page loads and lists all my articles from the DB in a drop down menu, but when I select the one I no longer require, it goes back to index as coded on the page but check my site it does not delete the article.

**my DELETE.PHP page is this:**

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once('../include/connection.php');
include_once('../include/article.php');

$article = new storearticle;

if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
   if (isset($_GET['title'])) {
         $id = $_GET['title'];
         $query = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM mobi WHERE promo_title = ?');
         $query->bindValue(1, $title);
         $query->execute();

         header('Location: index.php');
   }
   $articles = $article->fetch_all();
?>        
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Delete Article</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="../other.css" />
   </head>

   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <a href="index.php" id="logo"><b>&larr; Back</b></a>

        <br />
        <div align="center">
            <h4>Select an article to delete:</h4>    
            <form action="delete.php" method="get">
               <select onchange="this.form.submit();" name="title">
               <?php foreach ($articles as $article){ ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?>"><?php echo $article['promo_title']; ?></option>
               <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </form>    
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
<?php
} else {
     header('Location: index.php');    
}
?>
```

Can someone see where I am going wrong?

If you need any more info then please let me know.

Comment: can you print_r($articles); ..

Comment: hi user... I had yo change $id to $title as stated below. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning id by

```
$id = $_GET['title'];
```

and then you're trying to get it by `$title`. I think that is the problem :)